# Is there an identity between the associative identity and the constant identity?

Tags: universal-algebra

This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: [Is there an identity between the commutative identity and the constant identity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450890/is-there-an-identity-between-the-commutative-identity-and-the-constant-identity). Let our signature be that of a single binary operation $+$. I define the constant identity to be $x+y=z+w$. The associative identity is $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$. Is there an identity strictly between the two? Meaning, is there an identity $E$ such that the constant identity implies $E$ but not conversely, and $E$ implies the associative identity but not conversely? Since the answer to my previous question was affirmative, I suspect the answer to this question will be affirmative also. But I can't find such an identity.

Comment: Already there's an obvious pair of identity in between (the one saying that all triple products are the same).

Comment: Oh, it's a single one: $a+(b+c)=(d+e)+f$.

Comment: @YCor But is your identity strictly weaker than the constant identity? Isn't it equivalent to it?

Comment: Just take the semigroup $\{a,b,c\}$ with $aa=b$ and all other products equal to $c$.

Comment: @YCor Then you should state the identity as an answer.

Comment: But this is not a very exciting one. Better ask whether there is something between associativity and constancy of triple products?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a real motivation at looking specifically at varieties of magmas that are generated by a single identity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An identity $E$ that obeys all the claimed properties is
$$ E: x+(y+z) = (x+y)+w \hbox{ for all } x,y,z,w.$$

- $E$ is implied by triple constancy (and hence by constancy): obvious since both sides are constant in this case
- $E$ does not imply triple constancy (and hence does not imply constancy either): follows from considering the [left-zero semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup#Left_zero_semigroup) $x+y=x$ mentioned by arsmath
- $E$ implies associativity: obvious by specializing to $w = z$
- $E$ is not implied by associativity: follows from considering (say) addition on the integers

This candidate $E$ was located by pursuing the analysis in Pace's answer to isolate the form that $E$ had to take as much as possible, as described in the comments to that answer.  With a little more effort, it should be possible to entirely classify (up to relabelings and symmetries) the full set of identities $E$ that answer the question.

Here is the [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of the various identities discussed on this page and on the [related question linked by the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450890/is-there-an-identity-between-the-commutative-identity-and-the-constant-identity?rq=1), where the ordering is from stronger identities to weaker ones:

[image: Hasse diagram]

It might be a suitable undergraduate research project to extend this diagram to cover other short identities for magmas. EDIT: It might be a suitable graduate research project to find a way to do this automatically using proof assistants and possibly also machine learning/AI tools. (Some further discussion of this latter possibility can be found [here](https://mathstodon.xyz/@tao/110736805384878353), where I pose a concrete challenge of using such tools combined with human expert-hours to extend the above Hasse diagram to the five thousand or so other universal equational laws for magmas that involve at most four applications of the binary operation $+$.)

Comment: Nice! It's easy to place $x+ (y+z) = (x+w)+ u$ strictly between $x+(y+z) = (x+y)+w$ and $x+(y+z) = (w+u) +v$ by considering the operation on binary strings of length $\leq n$ where we concatenate and take the first $n$ digits, which is associative and where any product depends only on the first $n$ factors but doesn't depend only on the first $n-1$ factors.

Comment: Nice obsservation!  I added this (and also the law mentioned in a separate comment by YCor that wasn't equivalent to any of the previously discussed laws) to the diagram.

Answer (score 7):

This is a partial answer to YCor's improved question about an identity between associativity and constancy of triples, reducing it to a finite check.  (I'll use multiplicative notation below, for simplicity.)

Consider the multiplication on the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,0\}$ where $ab=d$, $dc=e$, and all other products are $0$.  This algebra satisfies any identity where both sides involve four or more letters (equivalently, 3 or more products) since such products are $0$.  Moreover, this algebra is not associative, since $a(bc)\neq (ab)c$.  So the identity we are looking for must have at least one side that involves no more than 3 letters.

Now consider the multiplication on the set $\{a,b,0\}$ where $aa=b$, and all other products are $0$.  This algebra satisfies constancy of triples.  Any identity where one side has three or more letters and the other side has fewer than three letters is not satisfied in this algebra.  So the identity we are looking for must have at least one side involving exactly 3 letters and the other side must involve at least 3 letters OR both sides involve two letters or less.

I believe the second option can be handled very easily, but in any case it is a finite check.  So, consider the first option.  Write such an identity as $t=t'$, where $t$ involves 3 letters exactly.  Thus, up to symmetry and renaming, $t$ is of the form $x(yz)$, or $x(yy)$, or $x(yx)$, or $x(xy)$, or $x(xx)$.

It is easy to check that all five options are always $0$ in the first algebra we constructed above.  So, if $t'$ involves four or more letters, then $t=t'$ is satisfied in the first algebra we constructed, but associativity doesn't follow.

Thus, $t'$ also involves exactly 3 letters.  In order to avoid $t=t'$ being again satisfied in the first algebra, we must have $t'$ of the form $(pq)r$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct variables.  These variables needn't be distinct from $x,y,z$.

We are now reduced to a finite check.

Comment: When you write "3 products", you actually mean "2 products (of 3 variable occurrences)", right?

Comment: I don't see the conclusion of the third paragraph. Another possibility is that both sides of the equation have strictly less than 3 variables occurrences.

Comment: Yes, I meant 3 letters, not three products.  That's now fixed.  Also, I'll handle that extra possibility you mentioned shortly.

Comment: To handle the case where $t,t'$ both have two letters or less, consider the free magma on four generators $a,b,c,d$, and then replace any expression of length greater than two by zero, thus giving a new magma $\{0,a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,ba,bc,bd,ca,cb,cd,da,db,dc\}$ with constant triples.  This magma will not obey the identity $t=t'$ unless $t,t'$ are identical strings, but then the identity is tautological and will not imply associativity.

Comment: If one similarly takes the free magma on three generators $a,b,c$ and replaces any element outside of $\{a,b,c,ab,bc,(ab)c, a(bc)\}$ by zero, one obtains a non-associative magma that can be used to rule out the case where $t$ and $t'$ both involve repeated variables.

Comment: Actually, your first magma already rules out the case where $t'$ has repeated variables and $t$ is of the indicated form ($x(yz)$ with $x,y,z$ not necessarily distinct).  Similarly if $t'$ has repeated variables.  So the only remaining cases are of the form $x(yz) = (pq) r$ where $x,y,z$ are distinct and $p,q,r$ are distinct, but there can be repetitions between $x,y,z$ and $p,q,r$.

Comment: OK, it turns out that a small perturbation of the associative axiom of this form works. See my other answer.

Comment: @TerryTao Excellent!  I upvoted your answer.

Comment: If $t\neq t'$ have both length $<3$, I don't understand @TerryTao's conclusion (one needs a non-associative law satisfying the identity). If length is 1,1, this implies constant. If length is 1,2, then this is not implied by constant law. If length is 2,2, we have (modulo flip) one of 1 $xy=zt$, 2 $xy=xz$, 3 $xy=zx$, 4 $xy=yx$, 5 $x^2=yz$, 6 $x^2=y^2$, 7 $x^2=xy$. Each of 1, 3, 5 implies constant. Each of 2, 4, 6, 7 (which is equivalent to 2) has obvious non-associative models. For instance if $f$ is a non-idempotent self-map on a set, the law $xy=f(x)$ satisfies 2 and is non-associative.

Comment: @YCor All of the laws you list are not obeyed by the magma I described in my comment, and so are not consequences of the triple constant law (which is one of the four requirements of the "improved" version of the OP question.  Of course, you can eliminate each of these laws by other means on a case-by-case basis, as you do in your comment, if you prefer.

Comment: @TerryTao Ah, indeed, I focussed on constancy of the law (instead of the triple law). I now see the point of your comment.